# Project name bar in main screen

Tags: android

When reviewing my app, I noticed that the blue bar on the top and the text in the bar (the project name) does not fit in the app.

I tried changing the project name into a more relevant one by going into REFACTOR -> RENAME but it said 'can't rename root module.' every time I tried to.

Is there a way I can either delete the blue bar or change the text on it?

Comment: The project name is not the name what will be reflected in the top bar of your app, you can find it in the main resources file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the resources strings object? Let me know if this makes sense... Look at the image that I've included. Go to res/values/strings.xml and make the app_name tag be empty

```
<string name="app_name"></string>
```

[image: path to resources strings]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Project name for Toolbar is defined in `res/values/strings` with key `app_name` by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In strings.xml, change `app_name`.

Or there's a `setText` method on the `ActionBar` class

To remove the bar depends on the theme used by that Activity (or if you explicitly show a `Toolbar` in the XML layout)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The name of your app is defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Inside, you'll see an Application object, with a property of ApplicationName. Set this to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

for remove top bar use in Manifest file :

```
<application ....
             android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getActionBar().setTitle("TITLE");
```

OR

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TITLE");
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of the action bar (your blue bar on the top) is set inside you `AndroidManifest.xml`, inside the activity tag:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

A good practice is to refer to a string stored inside `Strings.xml`

```
<string name="app_name">My cool app</string>
```

Comment: Thank you so much It looks so much better with the new text.